# elegant way to count multiple models and carry variables to a view - laravel

Tags: php, variables, laravel, laravel-4

I am cleaning up my code which I wrote as a hopeless noob.

I am creating a view with user statistics. 
My intention is to make a table showing both site and user stats, for instance:

```
Our repository has **1000** quotes **120** of them are contributed by you.
```

I have several models such as Book, Quotation, Excerpt etc.
To display the above, I define in my controller multipe variables

```
$userCountQuotes = count(Quote::where('creator_id','=',$userid)->get());
$CountQuotes = count(Quote::get());
```

and then pass them this way

```
return View::make('userworkspace.stats', compact('userCountQuotes','CountQuotes'))
```

I have about 10 different models to serve - 20 variables. Is there a more elegant way to get the numbers and display them in view?

My own solution: create a two-dimensional array of values

```
$stats= array
(
array("Books",22,18),
array("Quotes",15,13)
...
);
```

and then I have only one variable to pass to my view. Is that elegant enough?
Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lukasgeiter's answer is good, but I prefer another way which I'll add here as well.

Personally, I would make a method to get the count either within the model or a repository. I'd go the other way around for the `$userCountQuotes` - that is, starting with the user rather than with the quotes - and I'd use the built-in functionality for it.

Here's an example, which assumes that the models are properly related. In the User model:

```
public function quotesCount()
{
    return $this->quotes()->count();
}
```

And in the Quote model:

```
public static function countAll()
{
    return static::all()->count();
}
```

Then, in the view, pass the user and do this:

```
Our repository has **{{ Quote::countAll() }}** quotes - **{{ $user->quotesCount() }}** of them are contributed by you.
```

Comment: That's nice as well. Just note that it breaks MVC a *little* bit, because the view is doing the fetching instead of the controller...

Comment: It will allow me to put the output in various places in the view - so I like it! Thank you!

Comment: When you add {{ $user->name }} to the view, it is fetching data also, and it doesn't seem much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, instead of retrieving the results (`get()`) and then using `count()` you should use the `count()` method which will use an SQL count under the hood

```
$userCountQuotes = Quote::where('creator_id', '=', $userid)->count();
$CountQuotes = Quote::count();
```

Now for passing it to the view id use an array a bit a different structure:

```
$stats = array
(
    'Books' => array(
        'total' => 22,
        'user' => 18
    ),
    'Quotes' => array(
        'total' => 15,
        'user' => 13
    )
)
```

And here's what your view then would look like

```
@foreach($stats as $type => $values)
    Our repository has {{ $values['total'] }} {{ $type }} {{ $values['user'] }} of them are contributed by you.
@endforeach
```